# How to pass AccountId in http request?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on a new system using ASP.NET Core. The actor in the system (person or service) that places a request is a `User`. Users need to login in. The created token is used to authenticate in further requests.

We also have an `Account` that represents the legal entity. This can be a personal account, a business account or an affiliation. A user can act in the name of multiple accounts. A user can for example place an order for the user personally or in the name of a company. When the user has multiple accounts an account needs to be selected.

The user should be able to open multiple browser tabs and act as different accounts in each tab. Therefore on each request that has an association to a specific account the `accountId` needs to be passed.

We are debating how the `accountId` should be passed with the request.

Options are:

**1) JSON Web Token**
When adding the `accountId` together with the `userID` to the JWT a new JWT needs to be issued each time the account is changed. I have too little experience to understand the consequences for multi-tabs, but as far as I understand storing JWT in cookie or local storage means that the cookie is shared across all tabs and using JWT is no suitable option.

**2) Header**
A custom header could be used, but I read about issues with custom headers that might be striped from a request.

**3) Query Parameter**
For queries a query parameter is natural and filters the orders collection for the orders of an `accountId`. For commands it is technically possible, but is confusing to have extra data in the queryParameter and not in the body.

Get all orders placed by account:

```
GET https://example.com/api/orders?accountId={accountId}
```

Create order in the name of account:

```
POST https://example.com/api/orders?accountId={accountId}
```

**4) URI**

For example, create order in the name of account:

```
POST https://example.com/api/accounts/{accountId}/orders
```

Add an item to order:

```
POST https://example.com/api/orders/{orderId}/items
```

Get all orders placed by account:

```
GET https://example.com/api/accounts/{accountId}/orders
```

The accounts collection makes it clear that an order is placed under a specific account. When an item will be added the `accountId` is not needed to be passed, because it is already saved in the order. One just needs to check if the User has permission to access the order. It is also clear how to access the orders from an account. If the user can see all orders from all authorized accounts api/orders works well, too. Even it is technically correct, I don't like that not all requests concerning orders are using the orders collection only.

**5) Body**
For commands the `accountId` could be passed in the body. This works well and enables to use the simple URI /orders for `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`. For `PATCH` it needs to be considered that changing the `accountId` after an order is created is not an option by business rules. It doesn't work for `GET`.

**6) Body for POST, PUT, PATCH and query parameter for GET**
For commands like creations and updates of resources the `accountId` could be passed in the body while for queries a query parameter is used.

Currently, I'm wavering between 4) and 6), tending to 6). Since the `accountId` is the legal entity that places the order it is a property of the order. Passing it in the body is natural. Filtering with a query parameter for queries is also naturally. The URI approach is fine, too, but I prefer to keep all operations on the orders collection only.

Are there any other options? Are the any issues with those options that I overlooked or I'm wrong about? Are there any RFCs, practical criteria, problems that speak for or against an option? Are their common solutions to the problem? Thanks for any answer.

**Update:**

For a `GET` I see the two options:

```
GET https://example.com/api/orders?accountId={accountId}
```

or

```
GET https://example.com/api/acounts/{accountId}/orders
```

To my understanding both lead to the same result. The second Option 2 just implies that there is also a resource at `https://example.com/api/acounts/{accountId}`. Is there any criteria that helps deciding which option to choose?

For a `POST` I see the two options:

```
POST https://example.com/api/orders – with accountId in the body
```

or

```
POST https://example.com/api/acounts/{accountId}/orders
```

The options have the same considerations as for `GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) related Authentication/Authorization in asp.net core  first

[RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) For JWT

You mentioned

> storing JWT in cookie or local storage means that the cookie is shared
> across all tabs and using JWT is no suitable option

In fact,you could store the JWT in [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/window/sessionstorage)  which is not shared between different tabs. When you send request you could get jwt from session storage and add it to request header/query ...

You could decide how to read token with `OnMessageReceived` property of `JwtBearerevent`

For example,I tried with a project as below:

[image]

The controller generate the token:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get(string userName, string pwd)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwd))
            {
                var claims = new[]
                {                
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName)
                };
                var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Const.SecurityKey));
                var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(  
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                    signingCredentials: creds);
                return Ok( new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));

            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "username or password is incorrect." });

            }

        }
```

The controller under protected:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="Bearer")]
        
        public string Get()
        {
            return "protected";
        }
```

regist Jwt Auth in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x=>
    {
        x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(y=>
   
    {
        y.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer=false,
            ValidateAudience=false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey=true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Const.SecurityKey))
        };
        y.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
             {
                 context.Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Query["token"].ToString();
                 return Task.CompletedTask;
             },
            OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {


                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

codes in view:

```
<input  type="button" id="fetch" value="FetchToken" />
<input id="token"/>

<input type="button" id="display" value="display"/>
<input id="data"/>


<script src="~/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("#fetch").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/Api/Auth?username=J&pwd=123',
            method:'GET',
            success:function(response){
                alert(response)
                $('#token').val(response)
                sessionStorage.setItem('token',response)
            }
        });
    })
    $("#display").click(function(){
        var token=sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        $.ajax({
            url:'/Protected?token='+token,
            method:'GET',
            success:function(response){
                $('#data').val(response)
               
            },
            error:function(xhr,statue,error){
                alert(xhr.status)
            }
        });
    })

</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information about the session storage and JWT. Your answer doesn't help me to decide which option to choose to pass the accountId. If a staff user needs to act in the role of different accounts pasing the informaion in the JWT token is not a good solution, because the token would need to be changed on every call.

Comment: After a long discussion, we decided that the best solution is to use the JWT token to hold the userId and the accountId that the user is acting in behalf of.